# SQL query to finds rows containing a value in a column that also appears in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a team table represented as below.

`id    | name      | owner_id | members
------|-------------------------------------
1     | Tigers    |99        | 501,502,503
2     | Bears     |100       | 100,600,601,602
3     | Swans     |101       | 700,701,702
...`

A team has a name, an owner (a foreign key to a user's table), and members (a list of id's related to users in a user's table).

The point here is that while owners are implicitly team members, their id does not appear in the members column. In the above example, row #2 is an error (id 100 appears in members column).

**Question**
How can I query the table for rows which have owner_ids that also appear in members column?

Comment: can you tag your database as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

```
select * from tbl
where find_in_set(owner_id,members)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select owner_id,members from table
    group by owner_id,members
    having COUNT(owner_id) > 1
```